# Duplicate Database server in oracle 11g Listner is started but when connecting sqlplus / as sysdba tnsprotocol error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, duplicates, oracle11gr2

Hi I want a to build Duplicate Database server in oracle 11g with rman duplicate feature I install software only not full database during installation.
Listner is started but when connecting sqlplus / as sysdba get this error `ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adaptor error`
OS is Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_rman_82_duplicate_windows.htm